# Pagination on laravel

Tags: php, laravel, pagination

I have the route:

```
Route::get('/inventoryFromCat', 'infoController@getInventory');
```

And I have the method:

```
$inventory = DB::table('inventory')->where('category', $request->categoryId)->paginate(10);
$inventory->setPath('inventoryFromCat');
```

First page is okay, but the following is empty.
For example, first page:

[image]

Second page:
[image]
Url on first page:

```
http://localhost/inventory.site/public/inventoryFromCat?editCatName=&categoryId=1&_token=19DRwV4hv7RZUExqloz3fy3TAn9CSMad8BT2ktFq
```

Url on second page:

```
http://localhost/inventory.site/public/inventoryFromCat?page=2
```

Full function:

```
public function getInventory(Request $request)
    {
        if ($request->searchInput) {
            $inventory = DB::table('inventory')->where('id', $request->searchInput)->get();
            return view('admin/singleInventory', compact("inventory"));

        } else if ($request->categoryId) {
            $inventory = DB::table('inventory')->where('category',  $request->categoryId)->paginate(10);
              $inventory->setPath('inventoryFromCat');

            $category = $this->getCategory($request->categoryId, false);
            return view("inventoryFromCategory", compact("inventory", "category"));

        } else if ($request->invId) {
            $inventory = DB::table('inventory')->where('id', $request->invId)->get();


            return view("singleInventory", compact("inventory", "barcode"))->render();
        } else if ($request->invIdForEdit) {
            $category = $this->getCategory(null);
            $currentCat = $this->getCategory($request->invCat);
            $editInventory = DB::table('inventory')->where('id', $request->invIdForEdit)->get();
            return view("editInventory", compact("editInventory", "category", "currentCat"))->render();
        }

    }
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Do you have enough data to show in second page?

Comment: Of course. I have 4 or 6 records on second page

Comment: Please add complete function code in controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When calling `->links()` in your view, you need to add those additional query string parameters (`editCatName` and `categoryId`?). See 'Appending To Pagination Links' in the docs - https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/pagination#displaying-pagination-results

It should look something like:

```
$inventory->appends(['categoryId' => $categoryId, 'editCatName' => $editCatName])->links()
```

Obviously check that `$categoryId` and `$editCatName` are passed to your view as well.

Comment: Thank you so much)